# Login Prompt stays after unlocking Macbook using Touch ID

Tags: macbook-pro, unlock, touch-id

My office gave me Macbook Pro 15 inch recently with macOS Mojave version 10.14.5.

I configured my Touch ID, it is working fine.  When I unlock the system after locking it the login prompt does not go away.

If I enter the password it will go away.  If I press Cancel the screen and keyboard will be turned off and it comes back when I touch the trackpad or press any key.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this can happen if you use network authentication (like Active Directory), and your network password was changed.  Your fingerprint never changes, of course, but all your fingerprint does is unlock the password saved on your Mac.

If you change your password somewhere else (like on a Windows PC, or if an Active Directory admin changes it for you), your Mac won't know about the password change.

The fix is to only change your Mac's password using the Users & Groups preference pane in System Preferences.